# What probability distribution is this?

Tags: probability, signal-processing, normal-distribution

This image show a histogram (200 bins) of accumulated distances from a radar distance meter (very noisy).
The peak around 7 meters is an object. At thought this looked kind of like a normal distribution, at least if you ignore values <4m (which for this application is reasonable).

What I am trying to do is to filter out true distances based on the probability distribution.

[image]

Comment: Good grief... that indeed is noisy. In any event, if you don't get that many answers here, you could also try @ [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @J.M. Yeah, very noisy indeed, I can give CV a try too..

Comment: I find the title misleading. Maybe you mean "Which probability distribution might this be?".

Comment: Thanks for cross-posting on Cross Validated: here's the link to additional answers: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5430/how-would-you-filter-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it wasn't for the spike at 0 and the mode at around seven, it would look roughly lognormal to me

Answer (score 0):

The density function of distance-from-mean of a bivariate normal distribution takes the form $Ax e^{-Bx^2}$, which look pretty much like your noisy graph.

Comment: bivariate? Its really only one dimention - distance. I found that a log - normal distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) makes a decent fit..

Comment: Well, some radar dishes go round and round...

Comment: Ok, I see your point. Maybe I should have pointed out that it is a 1D radar.

Answer (score 0):

I would fit a straight line to the bins near but outside the peak and subtract this from the data, claiming that this level is the background.  Then you can do a 2D fit of the Gaussian parameters (mean and sigma) and see how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a (tri-modal) [mixture distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution).